# How to get ajax post data on controller method in .net mvc

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, json, model-view-controller

I am using jquery to post some data to a controller' method. I could successfuly post it like below.

```
POST http://localhost:16161/VisualObjectPairing/SaveParameters HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:16161

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 146

Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Origin: http://localhost:16161

X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36

Content-Type: application/json

Referer: http://localhost:16161/VisualObjectPairing/Index

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept-Language: en-US;en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

***DATA***

```
{"deviceId":"9",
 "SwitchStatus":"6/0/1",
 "InOperation":"6/0/2",
 "selectedInteractiveObjectSet":["5557","5558","5559","5560","5561","5562","5563"]}
```

But the fields on the data like ***SwichStatus*** and ***InOperation*** are dynamically added the form and can be more of them with different kind of names. So basically I couldnt put them on the controller method as parameter.

**The controller method is**

```
public JsonResult SaveKnxDeviceParameters(int deviceId, List<int> selectedInteractiveObjectSet = null)
{


}
```

The parameters, **deviceId** and **selectedInteractiveObjectSet** are automatically binded. Perfectly fine. But I want to get **SwitchStatus** and **InOperation** values manually from the Request (or whatever I can get) object but I cannot find any property that gives me the values of them. Request.Form is empty so I cannot use it like Request.Form["InOperation"].

Where should I get these values ?

Comment: Do you know what their names gonna be?

Comment: @Sam I get the names from Database

Comment: Then you can add a class with all names as field, add it as second parameter in controller and send a json with whatever names you got.

Comment: @Sam How can I add a class and pass it as a second parameter of the method if I create it at runtime

Comment: I mean keep an object ready in controller param to recieve the dynamic json. Any name not present in json will be null in the object. I hope I have understood you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are automatically bound by name. So you'll need to know these names at compile time or pass them as a key-value pair collection

```
{ "deviceId": 9,
  "parameters": [ {"key": "SwictchStatus", "value": "6/0/1" },
                  {"key":"InOperation", "value": "6/0/2" }],  
  "selectedInteractiveObjectSet": [] }
```

Now "key" and "value" are static names.

Here's a strongly-typed model example:

```
public class UploadModel
{
    public int deviceId { get; set; }
    public int[] selectedInteractiveObjectSet { get; set; }
    public Parameter[] parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult SaveKnxDeviceParameters(UploadModel model)
{
    foreach(var item in model.parameters)
    {
        var key = item.key;
        var value = item.value;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass additional variables to controller (which are dynamically added) you can use additional parameter `Dictionary<string, object> dynamicVariables` or `Dictionary<string, string> dynamicVariables` on server side. In this case you need to wrap all dynamic variables in single object in your JS and pass it to appropriate parameter in controller's action. E.g.

---

JS Code

```
var deviceId = getDeviceId();
var selectedInteractiveObjectSet = getSelectedInteractiveObjectSet();
var dynamicVariables = getDynamicVariables(); // assume function returns object like { "SwitchStatus":"6/0/1", "InOperation":"6/0/2"}
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/VisualObjectPairing/SaveKnxDeviceParameters',
        data: {
               deviceId: deviceId,
               selectedInteractiveObjectSet: selectedInteractiveObjectSet,
               dynamicVariables: dynamicVariables
              },
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) { ... }
});
```

---

Controller's action

```
public JsonResult SaveKnxDeviceParameters(int deviceId, List<int> selectedInteractiveObjectSet = null, Dictionary<string, string> dynamicVariables)
{


}
```